# How to strip out the username and samaccount from a gridview in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ldap

```
LDAP://CN=Joe Bloggs 111111,OU=Users,OU=Departmental Users,DC=micnet,DC=net
```

How would I strip out the username and samAccountName (111111) from a grdiview in c#?
My griview returns the above results when I search AD, but I want to strip most of the info out

Comment: The sAMAccountName is not part of the LDAP path, which is what you display. You cannot strip it from it - but, you need to create a `DirectoryEntry` for that path, and query its properties. to work with these (and check which properties you actually need and want), use [ADSI edit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354(v=ws.10).aspx), and ldp.exe (to test LDAP search queries).

Answer (score 0):

The result is LDAP path, of DS entry.
You can create [`DirectoryEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (need reference to [`System.DirectoryServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DirectoryServices%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), with that path, and then query the different properties of that entry (which include what you asked for), or, better from performance perspectives, do a search for that entry (with [`DirectorySearcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and retrieve the wanted properties with the search result.

Comment: You tries what?  Of course the CN (canonical name) is `Joe Bloggs 111111`. The sAMAcountName is one of entry's properties (You have a property named `Properties`... query it.

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = "LDAP://CN=Joe Bloggs 111111,OU=Users,OU=Departmental Users,DC=micnet,DC=net";
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(path);
string username = (string)de.Properties["displayName"][0];
string samAccountName = (string)de.Properties["samaccountname"][0];
```